# trying to get video stream from a Wi-Fi device via its local IP address in my Android app. How can I use this stream as local video in the Agora SDK?

Tags: java, android, agora.io

"I am attempting to retrieve a video stream from a Wi-Fi-connected device. By accessing the feed through its local IP address, I have successfully obtained it in my Android app. Now, I would like to integrate this stream into the Agora SDK as a local video source."

this is how i am getting the video stream in my app,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    surfaceView = findViewById(R.id.mjpegViewDefault1);
    try {
        Mjpeg.newInstance()
                .open("http://192.168.1.52:81/stream", TIMEOUT) // url to access the stream 
                .subscribe(inputStream -> {
                    surfaceView.setSource(inputStream);
                    surfaceView.setDisplayMode(DisplayMode.BEST_FIT);
                    surfaceView.showFps(true);

                }, throwable -> {
                    // Handle the timeout exception here
                    throwable.printStackTrace();
                    // You can also show a message to the user or take appropriate action.
                });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```